# Simple Django print() logging to Gunicorn access.log

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I just want my print statements to appear in *any* gunicorn log. I run gunicorn with the following:

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/the-app.log
LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
NUM_WORKERS=2
WSGI_APP=api.wsgi

exec gunicorn $WSGI_APP  -w $NUM_WORKERS -b 127.0.0.1:8040 --timeout=3000 --access-logfile=$LOGFILE --error-logfile=$LOGFILE  --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE --user=$USER --group=$GROUP
```

In the last line there, I've declared an access log and and an error log. My `print` statements do nothing though. Also, I haven't defined any logging in Django's `settings.py`. I feel I didn't need to since that one gunicorn config line got access and error logs working.

What can I do to be able to see `print` statements?

Comment: Instead of using `print`s you should use Django's logging. Then configure a logging handler (`logging.StreamHandler`) that outputs to the console.